# jQuery UI Remove Dropped Object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a simple jQuery UI project. I'm dragging an image inside a "blue" div to an empty "red" div.

I can insert image code to "red" div, as well. But what I really want is, after dragging completed, to remove the first item.

In summary, drag a picture to another div. Stick it to the top-left no matter where user drops.

```
    <script>
    var imgCode = '<img src="42.jpg" id="dragPic" alt="42" width="100" height="100">'; //This is my image code
        $(function() {
          $( "#dragPic" ).draggable(); //Image will be draggable
          $( "#red" ).droppable({ //Image has dragged into "red" div
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
              $( this )
                .addClass( "redDrop" ) //Custom CSS
                  .html(imgCode); //Insert image inside div
           /* Now I need to remove the image that user dragged. */
            }
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the item that's being dragged using "ui.draggable" inside the "drop" function.

```
      $( "#dragPic" ).draggable(); //Image will be draggable
      $( "#red" ).droppable({ //Image has dragged into "red" div
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
          $(this).addClass( "redDrop" ).html(ui.draggable); //Insert image inside div
          $(ui.draggable).css({position:''}); //reset the position of the dragged element
       /* Now I need to remove the image that user dragged. */
        }
      });
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ep0ucxcn/

Comment: thanks for your answer. it worked well. but I didn't get a part: which code deleted (actually moved) the original image? ".html(ui.draggable)" so what if I want to drag-drop same image again and again? You know, something like filling a square with smaller squares? also, I did not get that why we need to reset css. I'll appreciate if you explain.

Comment: I think you're looking for the "clone" helper, see the revised fiddle

Comment: one last question. any chance to give a custom css class to appended item?